# Convert JSON object to complex POJO

Tags: java, json, pojo

I have a problem converting a JSON object to my POJO object.
My POJO object is this one:

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String gender;
    private String id;
    private PswUser psw;
    private String state;
    ...

}
```

The User object has inside another object PswUser:

```
public class PswUser {

    private String id;
    private String psw;
    private String salt;
    ...

}
```

I tried to convert the JSON representation of my `User` to my `User.class` object like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(myjson.toString(), User.class);
```

but I keep getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field psw has type PswUser, got java.Util.LinkedHashMap

The only way I found to let it work was removing the "psw" object from my json, parsing the PswUser and then adding again the PswUser to the User like this:

```
JSONObject pswJson = json.getJSONObject("psw");
json.remove("psw");
User user = mapper.readValue(json.toString(), User.class);
PswUser pswuser = mapper.readValue(pswJson.toString(), PswUser.class);
user.setPsw(pswuser);
```

However this is a bad solution for me, I have way more complex objects that I have to parse, and doing this everytime would be a big problem.

UPDATE:

This is my input json:

```
{"firstName":"Mark","psw":{"id":"ag5zfmRlYnVn","psw":"01f0047c","salt":"597948b852bba"},"state":null,"id":"ag5zfm","gender":"male"}
```

UPDATE 2:

The problem is due to the fact that i get User.class and PswUser.class from my appengine server, importing a jar.
So my client code is able to convert my User object but it is unable to convert it if inside there is another complex object.

Comment: Do you realize that without seeing the JSON it's pretty much impossible for anyone to help you?

Comment: what JSON library do you use?

Comment: I added my input json. 
My json object is from org.json library. The object mapper is from org.codehaus.jackson.map

Comment: If you construct a `User` with a valid `PswUser,` and ask the `ObjectMapper` to convert that *into* JSON with `mapper.writeValueAsString()`, what does the output look like?

Comment: I tried as you said, but i got the same result. I created a simple user with the object PswUser set and converted to string, but when i try to convert it again to the user object it gives me the same exception as before

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to my problem.
I used the JacksonFactory class to parse my JSON string:

```
JacksonFactory factory = new JacksonFactory();
User user = factory.fromString(json.toString(), User.class);
```

The import i used is:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
```